# rails 4 redirecting to most recent created record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Building a simple messaging app, [using this tutorial](https://medium.com/@danamulder/tutorial-create-a-simple-messaging-system-on-rails-d9b94b0fbca1#.qi93y9c2o), and wanted to know if it's possible for me to redirect to the most recent updated record in the database?

**application.html.haml**:

```
= link_to 'Messages', :conversations
```

I want to be able to change this to `localhost:3000/messages` and then it'll automatically gets redirected to the most recent message recorded.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :conversations do
  resources :messages
end
```

**conversation.rb**

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end

end
```

**messange.rb**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id

  def message_time
    created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y at %l:%M %p")
  end
end
```

**messages_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @conversations = Conversation.all
  @messages = @conversation.messages
  if @messages.length > 10
    @over_ten = true
    @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
  end
  if params[:m]
    @over_ten = false
    @messages = @conversation.messages
  end
  if @messages.last
    if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
      @messages.last.read = true;
    end
  end

  @message = @conversation.messages.new
end
```

Not sure what information is needed, but just wanted to see if this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

#### routes.rb

```
get 'messages', to: 'messages#most_recent'
```

#### message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
  #Create a scope for get the most recent record
  scope :most_recent, :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 1
  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id

  def message_time
    created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%y at %l:%M %p")
  end
end
```

#### messages_controller.rb

```
def most_recent
  @message = Message.most_recent.first
end
```

Then you can use `@message` for display the most recent message in a `messages/most_recent.html.erb` view.

But if you still want to keep your `index` controller action working, then you will need to add a condition.

You will need to add a separate route for `most_recent` controller action

#### routes.rb

```
get 'messages/most_recent' #In this case is not necessary to specify controller action with to:
```

Then in your `index` controller action

#### messages_controller.rb

```
def index
  if SOME CONDITION HERE
    redirect_to messages_most_recent_path
  else
    @conversations = Conversation.all
    @messages = @conversation.messages
    if @messages.length > 10
      @over_ten = true
      @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
    end
    if params[:m]
      @over_ten = false
      @messages = @conversation.messages
    end
    if @messages.last
      if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
        @messages.last.read = true;
      end
    end

    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end
end

def most_recent
  @message = Message.most_recent.first
end
```